# Allow character variants in username

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to import some users from a phpBB forum and found an odd thing: in phpBB I have some users with weird characters in the username. Eg: Henriëtte .

The problem is that in Drupal I can't create 2 users with the username "Henriëtte" and "henriette". Apparently "Henriëtte" = "henriette" and this will give an warning saying that the username already exists.

Is there any way to import both usernames in Drupal? Thanks.

**[LATER EDIT]**

The database encoding is `utf8_general_ci`. Also, after further investigation the `user_load_by_name()` function is responsible for returning a valid user even if one letter is different (ë > e). Also, `user_load_by_name` will in the end use `entity_load()` to load the user object.

Comment: What sort of encoding is your database using?

Comment: utf8_general_ci

Comment: That was the problem. I changed it to `utf8_bin` and now it is working as expected

Comment: That's good news

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

The encoding should be `utf8_bin` not `utf8_general_ci`